# Sampling weights in Cox proportional hazards models

Tags: r, survival, epidemiology, survey-weights, selection-bias

I'd like to use [sampling weights](https://notstatschat.rbind.io/2020/08/04/weights-in-statistics/) in a Cox proportional hazards regression model to address selection due to different response probabilities. I'm calculating the weights as [Inverse Probability of Selection Weights](https://cdn1.sph.harvard.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1268/2021/03/ciwhatif_hernanrobins_30mar21.pdf) (Ch 8). They are not time-dependent.

I'm trying to understand the difference between the procedure used by `svycoxph` and that used by `coxph` (from 'survival') with `robust = TRUE` and `id` as the participant ID variable.

I read in the help file for `svycoxph` that:

> The main difference between svycoxph function and the robust=TRUE option to coxph in the survival package is that this function accounts for the reduction in variance from stratified sampling and the increase in variance from having only a small number of clusters.

My questions are:

- Does this statement imply that in the simple scenario described here (no stratified sampling, only differing response probability) `svycoxph` and `coxph` with `robust = TRUE` should give the same results? [When I test it it seems to be, but I'm new to `survey`, so could be an implementation error!]
- Under the hood, how do the procedures differ? Under what circumstances would the results be appreciably/importantly different?

Answer (score 1):

The two will give identical point estimates in this setting. Standard error estimates might be slightly different due to different degree-of-freedom corrections (like the $n$ vs $n-1$ issue in variances).

Under the hood, `svycoxph` calls `coxph` to get the point estimates.  They both then estimate the variance of the parameter estimates by the variance of the influence functions (equivalently: the sandwich estimator, the infinitesimal jackknife).

For `coxph` it is assumed that observations in different clusters are independent, so the estimated variance of the influence functions is just the variance of the cluster totals of the influence functions.

For `svycoxph`, it is possible to allow for stratified sampling  (which introduces negative correlation between sampling indicators, reducing the variance) and also sampling without replacement from a finite population (which also reduces variances).  It's also possible to allow for two-phase sampling, where a subsample is taken from your original sample based on the measurements in the original sample (eg, case-cohort designs). And it's possible to do post-stratification/raking/calibration of weights to use information from the whole cohort in the analysis of a subsample.

Using `coxph` tends to be conservative for all of these other possibilities, and if the `survey` package didn't exist, `coxph` with `robust=TRUE` would be a reasonable way to do many of those analyses.

In the other direction, I don't know if anyone has looked at what the various penalised frailty estimators available in `coxph` would do when given survey weights. It would be an interesting coincidence if they did something sensible; they weren't designed to do so.